# Etiquette on requesting LORs for multiple fields?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I am completing my last semester of undergrad studies and am considering two different healthcare fields to pursue in a graduate program (nursing and occupational therapy.) Both paths can be competitive so I'd like to apply for both and decide from there based on where I get in/can afford, as honestly I can see myself in either field. I realize I am a bit indecisive, but I'm working on it ,lol...and deadlines are approaching.

How should I approach potential LOR writers with this in mind? I fear they will judge me for my indecisiveness, and writing two completely letters would probably be unreasonable to ask for. How far ahead should I request the letters, and is it ok to ask for one from a professor I took a course with a few years ago?

Comment: Why do you want a reference from a professor whose course you took years ago? References should be up to date and talk about your potential to do research.